# End to End testing with protractor giving error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I was trying to going through the tutorial in the angularjs.org's angular-phonecat. In the stetp three I'm getting error for end to end testing with protractor. here's the error code.

```
Using ChromeDriver directly...
Cannot read property 'matcherFn_' of undefined
[launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 1

npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! cwd c:\angular-phonecat\angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\angular-phonecat\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What;s going wrong in here?

Comment: run `npm install` or `npm update` on your directory, it looks like a corrupted file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the latest 1.0.0 version of minijasminenode.
As a temporary workaround this hack worked:

- edit node_modules/protractor/package.json and change the minijasminenode dependency to <1.0.0 so it now reads like this:

> "minijasminenode": "<1.0.0",

- remove the minijasminenode directory:

> rm -r node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode

- reinstall the required modules:

> cd node_modules/protractor && npm install

Your e2e tests should now run. There's probably a more graceful way to achieve this.

See also https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/931

Answer (score 2):

Andrew's answer works for me. Thanks Andrew.

By the way, I also changed 'browserName': 'chrome' into 'browserName': 'firefox', as no chrome is installed in my linux box. Then it works.

Comment: plus 1 for adding firefox

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding firefox made the protractor tests run on my windows 7, where as on mac chrome was running fine, here is the full test/protractor-conf.js file

```
exports.config = {
   allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

   specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
   ],

   capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
   },

  firefoxOnly: true,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:2000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 for this...what if I want to use IE all versions as browserName:'internet explorer'... what should be replacing internet explorer above to host selenium server on IE (8+)browsers?  I referred this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue regardless of which posted solution I could find anywhere. As I run most of my projects through XAMPP, I found that my issue was due to the port been set wrong on the config page.

\test\protractor-config.js

```
 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8383/',     <-- Altered to suit xampp localhost port
```

Was previously

```
 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',
```

Hope this can help others out too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions but was still getting errors. Changing the protractor version in the main package.json file to "~0.20.1" so that it read `"protractor": "~0.20.1",` and running the command line as administrator worked for me.

After running it for the first time, it gives a ChromeDriver error. I fixed this simply by replacing the `chromeOnly: True` property in the protractor-conf.js file with the complete path to the driver itself, in my case: `chromeDriver: 'F:/Documents/Angular/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.9.zip'`

Not particularly sure whether using an earlier version is a good idea though.